# pyspark distributes load unevenly with parts increasing in double size

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, rdd

The output parts of my pyspark process are of uneven size, but predictably with a n**2 pattern (0,1,2,4,8,16 etc).  This is my process:

I load data from Google BigQuery like this:

```
dConf = {
    "mapred.bq.project.id": project_id,
    "mapred.bq.gcs.bucket": bucket,
    "mapred.bq.input.project.id": project_id,
    "mapred.bq.input.dataset.id":dataset_id,
    "mapred.bq.input.table.id": table_id
}

rdd_dataset_raw = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    "com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable",
    "com.google.gson.JsonObject",
    conf=dConf
)
```

Whose output looks like this (`rdd_dataset_raw.take(2)`):

```
[(0, u'{"group_id":"1","pertubations":"Current Affairs,Sport,Technology"}'), 
(67, u'{"group_id":"2","pertubations":"Current Affairs,Sport,Celeb Gossip"}')]
```

Some trivial processing, with repartitioning:

```
rdd_dataset = (
    rdd_dataset_raw
    .repartition(nr_partitions)
    .map(lambda t, json=json: json.loads(t[1]))
)
```

which looks like this:

```
[{u'group_id': u'1', u'pertubations': u'Current Affairs,Sport,Technology'}, 
{u'group_id': u'2', u'pertubations': u'Current Affairs,Sport,Celeb Gossip'}]
```

When I save the RDD to Google storage with:

```
rdd_dataset_raw.saveAsTextFile("gs://bucket/directory")
```

This creates `nr_partitions` part files.

However, these part files are not evenly sized.  They increase in `n**2`, where n is the part file number.  In other words,

`part-00000` contains 0 lines
`part-00001` contains 1 line
`part-00002` contains 2 lines
`part-00003` contains 4 lines
`part-00004` contains 8 lines
etc.

Most of these also finish practically immediately, where the later parts run out of memory.

What is going on!?  How do I make the partitions take even load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as replacing `repartition` with `partitionBy`:

```
rdd_dataset = (
    rdd_dataset_raw
    .partitionBy(nr_partitions)
    .map(lambda t, json=json: json.loads(t[1]))
)
```

Note this needed to be done as early as possible.  Passing an unpartitioned rdd and then partitioning later broke.

[Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.partitionBy)